# What do pomegranates of blue, purple and scarlet material look like?

Tags: exodus

This is the 1st time I'm asking this website a question.. But what do the pomegranates in blue, purple and scarlet material look like? Are they actual pomegranates (which as far as I know, are red... Wrapped up in fabric?

Comment: Are you referring to the yarn designs in the pattern of a pomegranate, but wondering if real fruit wrapped in yarn was used instead? Exodus 39:24
They made pomegranates of blue, purple and scarlet yarn and finely twisted linen around the hem of the robe.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the OP is referring to the pomegranates that form the hem of the me'il [robe] of the Kohen Gadhol [high priest]. See Exodus 28:33-34 and 39:24-26.

My understanding of these verses is the simplest, contextual meaning of what they looked like would be tassels: the blue, purple, and crimson threads that form the robe gathered and tied together. A tassel/knot with the loose ends hanging out visually resembles a pomegranate (crown pointing down).

You can actually see a reconstructed example at this website (scroll to the middle of the page) [warning: I am not endorsing this organization, their message, or their accuracy in anything except this particular example of the pomegranate tassels, which I found surprisingly well-done. The rest, not so much]:
http://www.mishkanministries.org/highpriest.php

Comment: +1 I like the replica of [Solomon's Temple](http://www.mishkanministries.org/kingsolomonstemple.php) from that site.